# How to make a1,a2, and a3 to be read in the looping?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a problem where I need to randomize the value in the array, but I need to declare a1, a2 and a3 outside because a1, a2 and a3 need to be equal to 100. But when I do that, there cannot be randomize.. the looping keep execute the same value of random.

```
a3=random.randint(0,1)
a2=random.randint(0,50)
a1=100-a2-a3
random_array =  np.array([np.array([ a2, a1, a3]) for _ in range(x)])
```

Here the result that I got:

```
[ 6 94  0]   
[ 6 94  0]  
[ 6 94  0]   
[ 6 94  0] 
[ 6 94  0]   
[ 6 94  0]  
[ 6 94  0]  
[ 6 94  0]   
[ 6 94  0]
```

Comment: `a3=random.randint(0,1,100)` makes 100 random values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `randint` inside the loop if you want to get different random values each time.

```
random_array = []
for _ in range(x):
    a3=random.randint(0,1)
    a2=random.randint(0,50)
    a1=100-a2-a3
    random_array.append([a2, a1, a3])
```

Answer (score 0):

As in hpaulj's comment Numpy's random functions can return numpy arrays.  This can remove the need for any explicit loops.

```
import numpy as np

n=10
a3 = np.random.randint(0,2, n)    # The upper limit is exclusive so randint(0,1) is always 0
a2 = np.random.randint(0,50, n)
a1 = 100-a2-a3

a1
# array([77, 72, 81, 57, 84, 60, 97, 54, 52, 86])

a2
# array([23, 27, 19, 42, 16, 39,  2, 45, 48, 14])

a3
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

If you want an array of arrays:

```
np.stack((a1,a2,a3), axis=1)
# array([[77, 23,  0],
#        [72, 27,  1],
#        [81, 19,  0],
#        [57, 42,  1],
#        [84, 16,  0],
#        [60, 39,  1],
#        [97,  2,  1],
#        [54, 45,  1],
#        [52, 48,  0],
#        [86, 14,  0]])
```